# Android get Sensor values from sensor

Tags: android

is there a way to root my Android  phone and get sensorinformation direct from the sensor or system?

LG marcel

Comment: Perhaps this question should be asked on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is no need to root your android phone,you can get the sensor Information directly by using its API's.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by getting the information in a "direct" way.

There are two types of sensors in the android sdk: sensors representing an actual hardware sensor (e.g Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) and virtual sensors like Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION which values are calculated based on the data of one or more sensors. Using the sensor types which represent real hardware allows you to read the data delivered from the sensor The problem with all kind of sensors in smartphones today is that there might be some kind of preprocessing (e.g lowpass filtering) involved and there is little documentation on where and how this is done as there is often no information on which sensor is used the device. I recommend reading [this article on android sensors](http://www.mobiledevmag.com/2011/07/using-available-sensors-in-the-android-platform-current-limitations-and-expected-improvements%E2%80%A8/).

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'am sry but the Information from Sensormanager are not enough! As an example -> BMA 150 have a samplerate of 1500Hz and I chek a lot of phones and get 50 Hz samplerate -> so I'am looking for a way to get  1500Hz

Comment: What do you mean by BMA? Specific Model of a sensor? As far as i can tell the samplerate is limited by the SDK and there is no way to bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

In android, you have the SensorManager class which give you the possibility to work with your sensors on the device (except the GPS and the camera sensor).

To understand how it works, see this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

If you have questions abaut this, feel fre to post them.